# Repartitioned USB drive (FAT32 to NTFS), now cannot mount/access from command line

Tags: usb, 16.04, ntfs

I needed to format and repartition my USB drive from FAT32 to NTFS in order to install **Node.js live-server** (cf. *[npm live-server install: symlink error (even when running as root/admin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427973/npm-live-server-install-symlink-error-even-when-running-as-root-admin)*). After switching to NTFS, I run the command `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /media/usb` and now I get this error:

```
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

When I run the command `fuser -m /media/usb`, I am greeted with this mess:

```
/media/usb:              1rce     2rce     3rce     5rce     7rce     
8rce     9rce    10rce    11rce    12rce    13rce    15rce    16rce    
17rce    18rce    19rce    20rce    21rce    22rce    23rce    24rce    
25rce    26rce    27rce    28rce    29rce    30rce    33rce    34rce    
35rce    36rce    52rce    53rce    55rce    57rce    58rce    59rce    
60rce    61rce    62rce    63rce    64rce    65rce    66rce    67rce    
68rce    69rce    70rce    71rce    72rce    73rce    74rce    75rce    
76rce    77rce    78rce    79rce    80rce    81rce    85rce    98rce    
99rce   137rce   139rce   140rce   141rce   142rce   143rce   144rce   
145rce   146rce   174rce   175rce   201rce   214rce   243rce   286rce   
298rce   305rce   327rce   445rce   453rce   483rce   496rce   497rce   
594rce   601rce   603rce   604rce   616rce   617rce   622rce   636rce   
638rce   641rce   651rce   656rce   675rce   676rce   699rce   758rce   
789rce   799rce   815rce   828rce   869rce   871rce   921rce   989rce  
1012rce  1016rce  1044rce  1137rce  1170rce  1171rce  1172rce  1173rce  
1174rce  1175rce  1211rce  1212rce  1213rce  1218rce  1250rce  1251rce  
1258rce  1260rce  1291rce  1335rce  1346rce  1358rce  1378rce  1398rce  
1401rce  1411rce  1414rce  1415rce  1418rce  1427rce  1429rce  1431rce  
1433rce  1442rce  1490rce  1616rce  1618rce  1622rce  1627rce  1629rce  
1630rce  1635rce  1641rce  1652rce  1678rce  1679rce  1684rce  1689rce  
1690rce  1691rce  1694rce  1698rce  1720rce  1727rce  1730rce  1744rce  
1785rce  1793rce  1794rce  1795rce  1799rce  1800rce  1806rce  1829rce  
1830rce  1834rce  1839rce  1857rce  1859rce  1876rce  1888rce  1892rce  
1899rce  1910rce  1914rce  1945rce  1969rce  1981rce  2054rce  2061rce  
2068rce  2075rce  2090rce  2126rce  2150rce  2166rce  2169rce  2172rce  
2247rce  2258rce
```

The USB drive appears and works fine via the File Manager, I just can't access it via the terminal. I don't know what to make of all that stuff above (the huge list of numbers), but apparently something is preventing the USB from mounting to the selected mount point on the computer.

Comment: Did you check the output of `mount` to see if the volume is already mounted?  It's quite possible it's already auto mounted by the file manager (which is a GUI and probably auto mounts removable media), which explains the mount error you are getting

Comment: How does the file system of a USB drive relate to installing Node JS on your computer?